# Distinct colors for R input and output in Rnw chunks - knitr

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I'd like to render R input and output code from the same Rnw chunk using two different colors so that they can be more easily interpreted. So far my attempts failed while using a custom CSS template, where any change in colors appear to systematically change both input and output.

Thank you for your time.
F

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Looks like it should be simple by using `background` option, see [doc](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-decoration).

Comment: The background option will change the background color. This is not what I need. Rather, I'd like to change the color of the code/text itself.

Comment: What output format? Title and question body mention RNW (=> LaTeX) but you also write about attempts using CSS (implying RMD => HTML).

Comment: Eventually a PDF output from a tex file.